# The callback is not working properly, am I doing it right or is it a library bug/unity issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, callback

i have a problems with RustRcon library

```
private void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if(timer >= updateTime && connectionChecker.Status)
    {
        try
        {
            rconManager.Client.SendCommand(new GetServerInfo((info) => {
                UpdateServerInfo(info);
            }));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            print(ex.Message);
        }

        timer = 0;
    }
}

private void UpdateServerInfo(RustRcon.Types.Response.ServerInfo info)
{
    print(info.Hostname);
    hostName_Text.text = info.Hostname;
}
```

after the server returns the callback, method `UpdateServerInfo()` fires 1 time, and everything is fine (only when when we contain `print(info.Hostname);`)

but if I add these 2 lines to it:

```
    print(info.Hostname);
    hostName_Text.text = info.hostname;
```

the server outputs information to the console **2 times**, the first time the correct `info.Hostname` and the second time `Null` as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Console]

what could be the problem or what am i doing wrong

essentially

```
hostName_Text.text = info.hostname;
```

should fill the text on the stage, but this does not happen because print is executed 2 times and then the code just ends

That is:

```
    print(info.Hostname);
    hostName_Text.text = info.hostname;
```

the print method is simply executed 2 times and that's it, nothing else happens, the code doesn't go any further

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious main issue I can see is that in general most of the Unity API is not thread-save and can only be used on the Unity main thread -> your async server callback method might be called on a different thread

You could rather try e.g.

```
// use a thread-safe stack
// stack because you only want to display the latest received
private static readonly ConcurrentStack<Action> actions = new ();

private void Update()
{
    // handle received actions on the Unity main thread
    if(action.TryPop(out var action))
    {
        action?.Invoke();

        actions.Clear();
    }

    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if(timer >= updateTime && connectionChecker.Status)
    {
        try
        {
            rconManager.Client.SendCommand(new GetServerInfo((info) => 
            {
                // instead of directly executiing the callback rather schedule it for the next Update call on the Unity main thread
                actions.Enqueue(()=> UpdateServerInfo(info));
            }));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            print(ex.Message);
        }

        timer = 0;
    }
}

private void UpdateServerInfo(RustRcon.Types.Response.ServerInfo info)
{
    print(info.Hostname);
    hostName_Text.text = info.Hostname;
}
```